# Text File to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a text file that I download at launch from my website. It saves it to the Documents directory in the app. I want to read and process that text file and turn it into an NSArray.
I tried this:

```
- (NSArray *)articleReason {
    NSString *filename3 = @"GameList.txt";
    NSArray *pathArray3 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory3 = [pathArray3 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *yourSoundPath3 = [documentsDirectory3 stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename3];
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:yourSoundPath3 isDirectory:NO];

    NSString *urlData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSArray *parsed = [urlData componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    NSIndexSet *indexes = [parsed indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSRange range = [(NSString *)obj rangeOfString:@"Reason:"];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }];

    NSArray *disallowed = [parsed objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
    NSString * myString = [disallowed componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    disallowed = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"Reason: "];
    return disallowed;


}
```

This does not work. The thing is, if I download the text file while making the NSArray, it ends up working. Here's that code:

```
   - (NSArray *)articleReason {
    NSString *stringURL = kGameURL;
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSString *urlData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSArray *parsed = [urlData componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    NSIndexSet *indexes = [parsed indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSRange range = [(NSString *)obj rangeOfString:@"Reason:"];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }];

    NSArray *disallowed = [parsed objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
    NSString * myString = [disallowed componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    disallowed = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"Reason: "];
    return disallowed;

}
```

Any idea why this is not working? I verified in the Documents directory that the text file is downloading correctly. I do the downloading of the file in didFinishLaunching in the App Delegate. Here's that code:

```
NSString *stringURL2 = kGameURL;
NSURL  *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL2];
NSString *urlData2 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSFileManager *fileManager2 = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *docsDirectory2 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path2 = [docsDirectory2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GameList.txt"];
[urlData2 writeToFile:path2 atomically:YES ];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to what the format of the text file is? It's a bit difficult to see through all the variable names. Also, you seem to have "Link: " in one example and "Reason: " in another. What is it that you want to store in the NSArray? For code that reads a text file and stores something in an array this seems a bit complicated.

Comment: I have multiple arrays doing this, copied the wrong one. Has the same code except for the reason/link line. What it does it downloads the .txt file, which is set up with certain data repeating with a word in front of it (multiple entries with a title, link, etc). The array searches through the text file, and adds the string with the certain information (a link, for example) to the NSArray. So basically, all entries with Link: in front of it are added to the array. That part works. I just want to know why reading from a local file doesn't work when download one does.

Comment: When a file is downloaded and saved locally, it's a "local file" just as any other. Actually, I can see no essential difference between those two code samples. Maybe you should define "does not work", because it doesn't seem like those two solutions would produce different results. I'd like to help, but what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the array isn't created when the URL is local. The array is empty.

Comment: You've got a fantastic debugger. Use it. Walk through the entire code to find out what is really happening. For example, maybe `urlData` is nil (so then of course everything else is nil). Don't ask others to guess for you. Use the tools you have to analyze exactly where things are going wrong.

Comment: I did what you suggested. Something goes wrong after the creation of Parsed. The array, parsed, is full. However, when searching through it with the NSIndexSet, it fails. The indexes that match are 0. I just don't see why this is different from when I do the same thing but download the file. One note: to get parsed to work, I had to change the encoding of urlData to NSASCIIStringEncoding, otherwise it would just be empty. Not sure why this is different from downloading the file first as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
[urlData2 writeToFile:path2 atomically:YES ];
Writeto file needed it include the encoding.